# ServiceStack.Logging with Log4net not showing correct stacktrace information

Tags: logging, log4net, servicestack

I've been switching to use ServiceStack.Logging on a small solution using Log4Net.
So far it took me a couple of minutes and everything is working fine.
The problem is the logs are a bit different after using servicestack...
The stacktrace (%stacktrace parameter of log4net), (also %line, %stacktracedetail etc...) are deeper than the call in my code.
Example:
I get stacktrace = Log4NetLogger.ErrorFormat for any stacktrace wherever it originated in my code.

This makes it difficult to see what line in my code raised an exception.
I could use the level parameter of %stack but this doesnt feel good.

Any idea ?